# Can we derive this from =Elim rule?

Tags: logic, substitution

I know we can derive something like this from =Elim rule:
$$\varphi(a,b)$$
$$b=c$$
$$\therefore\varphi(a,c//b)$$
But I want to know if we can also go ahead and derive something like this if there was some need to do so:
$$\varphi(a,c//b)$$
$$a=d$$
$$\therefore\varphi(d//a,c//b)$$
I tried to find a sample of such derivation with no success.

Comment: The double line means $c$ in place of $b$ ?

Comment: It means partial substitution meaning c being replaced for some or all occurrences of b in $\varphi(a,b)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question points the finger to a little detail not always clearly stated.

See : Dirk van Dalen, [Logic and Structure](https://books.google.it/books?id=u0wlXPHATDcC&pg=PA93), Springer (5th ed - 2013), page 93 :

> $$\frac { x_1 = y_1, \ldots, x_n = y_n \quad \quad \quad ϕ(x_1,\ldots, x_n) } { ϕ(y_1,\ldots, y_n)}$$
>
> where $y_1,\ldots, y_n$ are free for $x_1,\ldots, x_n$ in $ϕ$.
>
> Note that we want to allow substitution of the variable $y_i (i ≤ n)$ for some and not necessarily all occurrences of the variable $x_i$.

If we want to formulate the rule using the simultaneous substitution operator, we must have :

> $$\frac { x_1 = y_1, \ldots, x_n = y_n \quad \quad \quad ϕ[x_1,\ldots, x_n/z_1,\ldots,z_n] } { ϕ[y_1,\ldots, y_n/z_1,\ldots,z_n]}.$$

Compare it with a textbook based on *Natural Deduction*: Ian Chiswell & Wilfrid Hodges, [Mathematical Logic](https://books.google.it/books?id=JeUDUWYD5eQC&pg=PR1) (2007).

The $(= \text E)$ rule is defined [ [page 122](https://books.google.it/books?id=JeUDUWYD5eQC&pg=PA122) ] as follows :

> If $\phi$ is a formula, $s$ and $t$ are terms substitutable for $x$ in $\phi$, and $D ... (s = t)$, $D' ... \phi[s/x]$ are derivations, then so is
>
> $$\frac { D ... (s = t) \quad \quad \quad D' ... \phi[s/x] } { \phi[t/x]}$$

without further "comments" on $\phi[t/x]$.

The operation of *substitution* for FOL expressions is defined [ [page 110](https://books.google.it/books?id=JeUDUWYD5eQC&pg=PA110) ] as follows:

> **Definition 5.2.10** Suppose $E$ is an expression, $y_1,\ldots , y_n$ are distinct variables and $t_1,\ldots, t_n$ are terms such that each $t_i$ is substitutable for $y_i$ in $E$. Then we write
>
> > $E[t_1/y_1,\ldots , t_n/y_n]$
>
> for the expression got from $E$ by simultaneously replacing **each** [*emphasis mine*] free occurrence of each $y_i$ in $E$ by $t_i$.

The "trick" (see the derivation of *symmetry* of $=$, [page 122](https://books.google.it/books?id=JeUDUWYD5eQC&pg=PA122)) is the suitable choice if $\phi$.

---

We can see also the Hilbert-style version of *equality axioms* in:

- Herbert Enderton, [A Mathematical Introduction to Logic](https://books.google.it/books?id=dVncCl_EtUkC&pg=PA112) (2nd ed - 2001), page 112:

> $x = y → (α → α')$
>
> where $α$ is atomic and $α'$ is obtained from $α$ by replacing $x$ in **zero or more (but not necessarily all)** [*emphasis mine*] places by $y$,

where the use of the symbolism for *substitution* ( $\alpha^x_t$ in Enderton's book) is carefully avoided.

---

---

Having said that, here are some legitimate applications of $(= \text E)$:

> > $\dfrac {x =y \quad \quad \quad x^2 + y^2 > 12x }{ 2y^2 > 12x}(\text {partial substitution})$
> >
> > $\dfrac {x =y \quad \quad \quad x^2 + y^2 > 12x }{ x^2 + y^2 > 12x}(\text {no substitution})$
> >
> > $\dfrac {x =y \quad \quad \quad x^2 + y^2 > 12x }{ 2y^2 > 12y}(\text {total substitution})$

Comment: So what do you suggest this page https://logic-1.butterfill.com/units/unit_110.html#slide-4 means by P(m) ?

Comment: Or page 8 of this pdf http://people.cs.ksu.edu/~tamtoft/CIS301/Fall04/Slides/04.pdf by P(u) ?

Comment: @Pooria - Not sure to understand: "not necessarily all" does not mean : "necessarily not all". If we have only one occurrence of $x$ in $\varphi(x)$, only two possibilities are left (zero or more...) : either *(i)* **no** subst at all... and we are loosing our time, or *(ii)* one occurrence of $x$ is subst, that means **all** occurrences.

Comment: Well focusing on =Elim rule itself, can you plz answer my previous question?

Comment: I just found a solid book, P(m) is the result of replacing some or all occurrences of n in P(n) by m and P(u) is alike.

Comment: @Pooria - perfect.

Answer (score 1):

The derivation makes sense, but the notation is a little confusing. To be specific, while it does make sense in the first inference to write $\varphi(a,c//b)$ to indicate that the *conclusion* is a statement that results from replacing any (which may end up being all, some, or none) of the $b$'s with $c$'s, to use this notation as a *premise* in the second inference is a little weird, because the premise is something you have, rather than something you end up with. Indeed, if we were to replace different $b$'s with $c$'s in $\varphi(a,c//b)$ as compared to which ones we replace in $\varphi(d//a,c//b)$, then the inference is invalid!

So, given that in the second inference you are in fact leaving any of the $b$'s (and $c$'s) alone, you really shouldn't use this substitution notation for them, but use it just for the substitition of $d$'s for $a$'s, as that is what you are doing. Hence, as Mario said, the second inference is really:

$\varphi(a,c)$

$a=d$

$\therefore \varphi(d//a,c)$

Comment: According to what I have seen now the $\therefore\varphi(t_2)$ line of description of =Elim rule does seem to be indicating replacing every single occurrence of $t_1$ in $\varphi(t_1)$ not just some of them, as I said it's $\therefore\varphi(t_2//t_1)$ that states replacing just some aka partial substitution, so I think you've been a little wrong in my previous question!

Comment: @Pooria QIt really should be *some*, not *all*. If it says *all*, then unless they have a way to do it some other way, the system would not be able to derive $P(a,b)$ from $P(a,a)$ and $a=b$, and since that *is* a valid inference, the system would not be complete!  Where did you read this?

Comment: Well in P(a,a) there are two variables both instantiated by 'a' isn't it that way? then each 'a' in the body of formula relates to one of variables, and so when you write P(a,b) not every 'a' gets replaced by 'b' just those relating to second variable get, that's my opinion, also why should $\therefore P(t)$ mean replacing anything in the first place?

Comment: @Pooria Right, so *not* all $a$'s are being replaced, and that's what you want to be able to do.

Comment: So do you think that is right?

Comment: It's // that indicates replacing meaning $\therefore P(t_2//t_1)$ involves replacing but not $\therefore P(t)$.

Comment: And even better now, P(a,b), P(b,a) and P(b,b) don't need anything to be replaced at all they're standalone, so by a=b and P(a,a) you can easily achieve P(a,b), P(b,a) and P(b,b)

Comment: So overall =Elim rule doesn't even involve replacing terms with each other, it's just instantiating a variable with another term!

Comment: @Pooria The $= Elim$ always involves replacing one term with another. Those terms can be atomic (which can be individual constants like $a$ or $0$ and, in *some* systems, variables like $x$ and $y$), but they can also be complex (like $a \times b$).

Comment: @Pooria From $P(a,a)$ and $a=b$ you can indeed infer $P(b,b)$, $P(a,b)$, and $P(b,a)$, and even $P(a,a)$. I don't know why you would ever do the latter, but it still follows the rule: you can replace *any*, i.e. all, some, or none!

Comment: Just read it on a book on google books, $\therefore\varphi(t_2)$ is result of replacing some or all occurrences of $t_1$ in $\varphi(t_1)$ by $t_2$, funny thing now is I don't know what // would be for anymore!

Comment: @Pooria OK, so there it says *some* as well. Good!  The // is simply to explain how the rule works, i.e. that you are replacing some (instances of) term with another term. It is not part of the logic formula though, if that's what you were thinking; rather, it tells us what happens to the formula. This is exactly why I prefer to write that the result is $\varphi(t_2)$ ... with the understanding that $\varphi(t_2)$ is the result of substituting any $t_1$'s with $t_2$'s on the basis of $t_1=t_2$.

Comment: Also regarding inferring P(a,b) from P(a,a) and a=b, at least one occurrence of term 'a' needs to remain in P(a,b) and we can literally replace any occurrence of term 'a' in P(a,a) right?

Comment: @Pooria Correct!

Comment: Also just not to be missing any points, inferring P(b,b) from P(a,a) and a=b we don't have to replace every term 'a' right? (personally don't see any reason to have to)

Comment: @Pooria Given that there are two $a$'s in $P(a,a)$ to begin with, and that both of them have been replaced once we get to $P(b,b)$, we *did* replace all of the $a$'s.

Comment: OMG I see what my mistake has been all the time :)